# Login form validation in Javafx using sqLite database

Tags: java, sqlite, validation, javafx

i have written the following code in Javafx to validate a login form using sqLite database . but the problem is it always throws the same error "wrong userName or Password" although i am putting the valid Username and Password which is also in Database.

Keep in mind that the connection with database file is successful because i am testing it before inputting any info but don't know why its not validating .
also if there is another way of validating form (easier than this) please suggest me.
Thanks !

This is **LoginModel.java** class

```
package sample;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class sqliteModel {
Connection connection;

public sqliteModel() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
    connection = sqliteConnection.Connector();
    if (connection == null) System.exit(1);
}

public boolean isDbConnected() throws SQLException {
    return !connection.isClosed();
}

public boolean loginValidateFunc(String userName, String password) throws SQLException {
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement;
    ResultSet resultSet;
    String query = "select * from UserDetails where Name = ? and Password = ?";

    try {
        preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(query);
        preparedStatement.setString(1,userName);
        preparedStatement.setString(2,password);
        resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
        if (resultSet.next()) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
}
}
```

This is **sqliteConnection** class

```
package sample;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class sqliteConnection {
    public static Connection Connector() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {

            Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:UsersDatabase.sqlite");
            return conn;
    }

}
```

And this is the method in **Controller** class.

```
package sample;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.ToolBar;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.net.URL;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class Controller implements Initializable {
    public Controller() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
    }

    @FXML
    private ToolBar ttlbar;
    @FXML
    private TextField mailfield, passfield;
    @FXML
    private Label errorlabel, closebtn;

    public void login_func() throws Exception {

        String m = mailfield.getText();
        String p = passfield.getText();
        try {
            if (sqlModel.loginValidateFunc(mailfield.getText(),passfield.getText())) {
                errorlabel.setText("Login Success !");
            }
            else {
                errorlabel.setText("Wrong Email or Password !");
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
//            errorlabel.setText("Wrong Email or Password !");
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
    }


    public void closeFunc() {
        Stage s = (Stage) closebtn.getScene().getWindow();
        s.close();
    }

    public sqliteModel sqlModel = new sqliteModel();

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        try {
            if (sqlModel.isDbConnected()) {
                errorlabel.setText("Connection Successful !");
            } else {
                errorlabel.setText("Connection Not Successful !");
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: `where Name` or `where Username` ?

Comment: Instead of `return false;` in `catch` make `e.printStackTrace();` and show us the error?

Comment: Column name is "Name" so its Name !

Comment: Error:(45, 5) java: missing return statement   is the error after e.printStackTrace();

Comment: yes i mean `e.printStackTrace(); return false;`

Comment: yes make both of them `e.printStackTrace();` and return a line and make `return false;`

Comment: oopppsss .....that was my fault ...but its you who helped my debug the error Thanks a lot ..wasted almost 3 hours and found that the Database file path was wrong !

Comment: haha ok @RAO HAMMAS good luck it happen to the best of us ;)